WinCHM never opens a .wcp file and the preview only shows a white screen
Related to this question, my WinCHM Pro application (version 5.53) will not even open, let alone allow me to view the table of contents of a help file directory.
When I attempt to start WinCHM by any means, and I select a valid.wcp file, the Splash screen pops up pictured below, but the preview of the application only shows a white screen alss pictured below:


What I tried

I tried to use the Windows + Arrow Direction keys in case it was off screen, but that was not the case.

I attempted to open the application as an administrator to no avail.

I attempted to go to the original install directory. It did mention something about the WinCHM command, but my command line, nor my Powershell saw this command as a valid one. The description of the command is quoted below:
 Usage: WinCHM [path]projectName [/[H][W][D][P][S]]

 /H : Compile html help
 /W: Create Web help
 /D: Create Microsoft Word document
 /P: Create PDF
 /S: Create Single HTML file

 Example 1:

 Open project "c:\project\a.wcp" and compile the html help(chm).

 WinCHM "c:\project\a.wcp" /h


 Example 2:

 Open project "c:\project\a.wcp" and create html help, web help and single html file at the same time.

 WinCHM "c:\project\a.wcp" /hws


Also in the install directory, I attempted to find if there were any error logs, however none could be found.


Question
How do I get my WinCHM to open a .wcp file if the preview is just showing a blank white screen?

Has the 15-day period of the trial version of WinCHM expired or do you have a registered full version? [Edit] your question to add this information. Check to open sample.wcp from ..\Documents\WinCHM Projects\Sample Project\ by double-click. Just a thought - save your project files and try to update WinCHM Pro to  Version 5.53 (at your own risk).

@help-info.de I have updated and added a picture of the splash screen. Issue still occurs.

I cannot reproduce the blank white screen on my PC. You should contact WinCHM support with your registered full version.
